# Syntax error: unexpected token "-"

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm doing a web application, and when I started writing the code in JavaScript I'm getting this error:

```
Syntax error: unexpected token "-"  javascript
```

I'm using Aptana Studio 3. I thought it was Aptana's problem, so then I tried with Eclipse, but still got the same error. Eclipse shows me this error:

```
Cannot return from outside a function or method.
```

Here's my function:

```
function www_ebest_eu_company_node_service_task-slot-info () {
    this.typeMarker = 'www_ebest_eu_company_node_service_task-slot-info';
    this._endDateTime = null;
    this._number = null;
    this._orderId = null;
    this._startDateTime = null;
    this._taskId = null;
    this._taskStatus = null;
}
```

I have many functions like this, and for every of them I'm getting the same error.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 6):

`www_ebest_eu_company_node_service_task-slot-info` is not a valid JavaScript identifier.

Comment: what does you mean with that? because the problem seems to be the "-" since I tried replacing the "-" with "_" and it seems to work :)

Comment: Yes, @alisnehx, that's right.  JavaScript does not allow "-" in identifiers.

Comment: Thank you..It seems I have a big problem then since I have an auto-generated long code with cxf apache from wsdl to js..So it's impossible traying to replace manyally everyone of them!

Comment: @alisnehx You will have to alter the code generation tool, or write a short program that alters the auto-generated output.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use hyphens in JavaScript function names:

```
function www_ebest_eu_company_node_service_task-slot-info () {

// Should proabbly be
function www_ebest_eu_company_node_service_task_slot_info () {
//---------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Oh yes thank you! I notice it in fact,so there is no way on accepting  the "-" like a part of the function's name?

Answer (score 3):

A hyphen "-" is not a valid character for naming variables or functions.  The hyphen is used for arithmetic, subtraction, and not for naming variables.  You can replace the hyphens with underscores or go with a CamelCase notation.

Answer (score 2):

Dashes are not allowed in identifier (function, variables, etc) names. Stay consistant with underscores or camelCase.